# Android glFramebufferTexture2D texture corruption

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to use `glFramebufferTexture2D` to render to a texture, this works fine on Windows, Linux, and in webgl via emscripten. But on Android using the NDK I get
[image: this bizarre result].

This is meant to be a blue 50x50 rectangle at 0, 500 on an empty texture size 100x2000, in a viewport of 720x1184, but I seems to be getting some of the Android ui texture and it's being repeated vertically.

It seems to get worse the larger I make the empty texture, it doesn't appear if it's 100x100.

I don't think I should even be able to access those texture, is this some kind of texture underflow, or maybe I'm running out of graphics memory?

Comment: Might be that OpenGL ES requires power of 2 sized textures unless there is a vendor extension permitting other sizes.

Comment: Mm, I should of noted that, but I've tried it power of 2 textures.

Comment: Do you clear the texture? If you're not clearing it and not rendering to all parts of it, the contents are allowed to be random junk (including showing parts of the Android UI)

Comment: @Columbo Wow, it was so obvious, but took me over a day, this code has worked for years so I was looking elsewhere. I was under the impression that glTexImage2d given NULL data created a zeroed texture. But turns out that's not always true.